# First meeting between Hanuman and Shree Rama

Tags: scripture, ramayana, rama, hanuman

This [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanuman#Meeting_with_Rama) article describes that when Sugreeva sent Hanuman as an emissary to meet Rama and Lakshmana. It also claims that on seeing Hanuman, Shri Rama praised Hanuman greatly.

How is this meeting described in the scriptures?

I am specifically interested in the original Sanskrit Shlokas.

Answer (score 6):

The first meeting of Rama and lakshmana with Hanuman is described in the *[Valmiki Ramayana Kishkindha kanda sarga 3](http://valmikiramayan.net/utf8/kish/sarga3/kishkindha_3_frame.htm)*. Hanuman speaks very politely. From those verses, we can learn how we should speak to strangers who are superior to us.

Hanuma completes series of his questions and introduces himself as a minister of Sugriva to Rama and Lakshmana. Then Rama was very well pleased by the words of Hanuma and turns to Lakshmana and speaks with him. Here Rama did not speak to Hanuma directly because He is following imperial protocol. An emperor does not indulge into a conversation with an inferior but uses his messengers or envoys to do such. We can also notice this type of conduct from Ravana in sundara kanda where he uses his minister Prahasta to talk with Hanuma.

**Following are the verses used by Rama to praise Hanuma**:

> सचिवो अयम् कपीन्द्रस्य सुग्रीवस्य महात्मनः |
>   तम् एव काङ्क्षमाणस्य मम अन्तिकम् इह आगतः || 4.3. 26
>
> तम् अभ्यभाष सौमित्रे सुग्रीव सचिवम् कपिम् |
>   वाक्यज्ञम् मधुरैः वाक्यैः स्नेह युक्तम् अरिन्दम || 27
>
> न अन् ऋग्वेद विनीतस्य न अ--यजुर्वेद धारिणः |
>   न अ--साम वेद विदुषः शक्यम् एवम् विभाषितुम् || 28
>
> नूनम् व्यकरणम् कृत्स्नम् अनेन बहुधा श्रुतम् |
>   बहु व्याहरता अनेन न किंचित् अप शब्दितम् || 29
>
> न मुखे नेत्रयोः च अपि ललाटे च भ्रुवोः तथा |
>   अन्येषु अपि च सर्वेषु दोषः संविदितः क्वचित् || 30
>
> अविस्तरम् असंदिग्धम् अविलम्बितम् अव्यथम् |
>   उरःस्थम् कण्ठगम् वाक्यम् वर्तते मध्यमे स्वरम् || 31
>
> संस्कार क्रम संपन्नाम् अद्भुताम् अविलम्बिताम् |
>   उच्चारयति कल्याणीम् वाचम् हृदय हर्षिणीम् || 32
>
> अनया चित्रया वाचा त्रिस्थान व्यंजनस्थयाः |
>   कस्य न आराध्यते चित्तम् उद्यत् असे अरेः अपि || 33
>
> एवम् विधो यस्य दूतो न भवेत् पार्थिवस्य तु |
>   सिद्ध्यन्ति हि कथम् तस्य कार्याणाम् गतयोऽनघ || 34
>
> एवम् गुण गणैर् युक्ता यस्य स्युः कार्य साधकाः |
>   तस्य सिद्ध्यन्ति सर्वेऽर्था दूत वाक्य प्रचोदिताः || 4.3.35

**The following is the translation of the series of the above verses**:

> He is the minister of that noteworthy soul and king of monkeys, Sugreeva... whom alone I cherish, but he himself has drew nigh of me, on his own. Soumitri, with this minister of Sugreeva, the knower of sententiousness and a pleasant worded one, and one with friendliness you exchange pleasantries with that enemy destroyer Hanuma.Nay...the non-knower of Rig Veda, or the non-rememberer of Yajur Veda, or the non-scholar of Saama Veda can possibly, or truly speak this way."Definitely grammar is severally and comprehensively learnt by him and though much is said by him not a single word has gone amiss of verbiage... **On his face or eyes, or on forehead or brows, or on other faculties of expression no fault is found...even at the least**. "Unexpanded, un-doubtful, un-delaying and non-dissonant is the tenor of his speech, and it comports in his chest or throat in a medium tone..."He has orderly refinement in speech that is remarkable and un-delaying, and he speaks propitious words that are heart-pleasing. **His speech is generated in three places is enthralling and whose heart is it that is disenchanted, even that of an enemy after raising his sword at him, on hearing his speech**. Oh, faultless Lakshmana, if this sort of envoy is not there to a king, really how can that king accomplishes his ways and means...

Later Hanuman who is a wordsmith is praised by another wordsmith Lakshmana. Then Hanuman escorts the brothers to Sugreeva and other monkeys.